# How can I get crowdsale data?

Tags: the-dao, history

Is there anywhere an access to crowdsale data gathered in a similar way as this kicsktarter data -- https://webrobots.io/kickstarter-datasets/ ?

Comment: Hi there. By "crowdsale" do you mean Ethereum-based token "ICO" (Initial Coin Offering)? Or are you talking specifically about TheDAO (as per your tags)? For either of these, what data are you specifically looking for?

Answer (score 2):

[TokenMarket offers such database](https://tokenmarket.net/blockchain/all-assets).

- We collect background information such: team members, news articles, Facebook posts, Twitter posts
- We collect financial information such as: number of investors, average investment, investments over time, etc.
- We do not offer public data dumps, but the data is readable on our website

Disclaimer: I work for TokenMarket.